# Unable to launch program via powershell via Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-10, powershell, task-scheduler

I have a simple powershell script that detects if a program is running and if it isn't it launches the program.  It works fine when I right-click and "Run with PowerShell" the script, but changing the default program for .ps1 to powershell and double-clicking it does not. Also, it does not work in task scheduler.  For refernce, here is my script:

```
$filebound = get-process FileBound.Enterprise.ChainEditor -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($filebound -eq $null)
{
    start-process -filepath "C:\Program Files (x86)\FileBound\Importer Professional\FileBound.Enterprise.ChainEditor.exe"
}
```

I cannot find the proper way to argument the action in task scheduler to get it to work.  When it runs the task, the power shell screen comes up and disappears, but the application doesn't run (same behavior as double-clicking).

here is my Task info:

```
Run only when user is logged in and run with highest priveleges checked.  Configured for Windows 10 (it's a windows 10 vm).
Triggers at startup and repeats every 30 minutes indefinitely.  Enabled is checked
Actions starts a program (powershell)
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
with argument (stolen from someone else) -command "& C:\Filebound\Test.ps1" -NonInteractive
Only Condition checked is Wake computer to run task.
Settings are Allow Task to run on demand and Run task as soon as possible are checked.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  It was related to the argument in Task Scheduler.
Once I set it to:   `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\Filebound\Test.ps1` everything worked.

Side note, I had to adjust the task to be "When computer is Idle" as trigger instead of "At startup" to make it more reliable.

Comment: You used -command but you should've used -file. In this answer, you don't specify -file, so powershell has to guess. In this case it works, but its better to just use -file always.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell to set execution policy to unrestricted, then you don't need to specify `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` parameter every time you need to run a ps1 script.

You are able to open PowerShell, but this method requires administrative privileges, use this to open elevated PowerShell:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>→type `PowerShell`→<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then paste these into PowerShell window:

```powershell
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell" -Name EnableScripts -Type DWord -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell" -Name ExecutionPolicy -Type String -Value Unrestricted
```

And then you don't need to bypass execution policy to run scripts.

This is equivalent to changing this Group Policy:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>→type `gpedit.msc`→<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Navigate to:

```powershell
"Local Computer Policy"→"Computer Configuration"→"Administrative Templates"→"Windows Components"→"Windows PowerShell"
```

in the left panel, click on "Windows PowerShell".

In the right side, double click "Turn on Script Execution", click "Enabled", and choose "Allow all scripts" in the "Execution Policy" dropdown list, click <kbd>Apply</kbd>, then click <kbd>OK</kbd>.